# How do I forward Wordpress registration information to a client?

Tags: wordpress, forms, content-management-system, registration, forwarding

I'm working on a Wordpress site. Our client wants to have a custom registration form (not just user and password but other info such as name, phone number, city, etc). Once the registration is completed, the client wants this data (the registration info) to be forwarded to her in an email. Is there any plugin or any way to accomplish this?
I'm using the simplr registration form plugin to generate the form, but I could change to another one if need be.
Thanks for any help you can provide.
Best,
CPG

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying Sideways8 Custom Login and Registration. Here is link to the plugin. This may help you accomplish what you are looking for with a plugin.

http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/s8-custom-login-and-registration

Not sure what type of knowledge you have with PHP but this is the best thing I could suggest using a plugin.

Let me know how this works out!